# Japanese Anime/Arcade 'Shing' sound

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesis, game

I am trying to recreate the 'shing' sound which can be heard at 1:22 in this video - https://vimeo.com/106517842 and also another variation at around 0:32 in this one - https://vimeo.com/106517842.

I'm having a little trouble getting it just right (it needs to sound 100% authentic for this project). I'm thinking maybe synthesised sounds with a fast pitch envelope could work, rather than processed metal sounds which is the other possible route.

Any ideas/tips would be super helpful. Plus this is quite a commonly used sound in a lot of japanese cartoons and arcade games, so perhaps there is some kind of 'trick of the trade' established method for creating them someone might know about!

Comment: Very interesting question. Clients have been asked me for these kind of sounds a couple of times. Sadly I don't have a straight answer for you. I don't know if there is any common source for these. My guess would be they come from some sampler or synth used in japan in the 80's and 90's and they became popular, almost cliché. Maybe someone with knowledge about roland and casio instruments from that time can help.

Comment: The only real life instrument that produces this kind of rise in pitch is the chimes. Might be worth looking in to synthesized variants of it.

Another ideea might be to layer stuff at a constant pitch and then modulate it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a 6 min you tube video on how to make this "shing" sound.

I always thought of it as a sword sound effect. The guy in this video makes it from three different sounds. The first is a bass layer that he says he got by shaking a belly dancer's scarf (like http://www.ebay.com/itm/Belly-Dance-New-Chiffon-Hip-Scarf-Coin-Wrap-Belt-Skirt-Black-Color-Gold-Coins-/151958813751?hash=item2361737c37:g:3LUAAOSwuYVWofS2 ) whilst bowing a metal lamp.

The second sound is the actual sword sound, which he got by clanging some actual knives together.

The third sound is also a bass layer that he got by placing a microphone inside a metal dumpster being rattled around with some metal stuff on top.